# Re-sizing matplotlib markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, markers

I see a ton of questing on re-sizing marker relative to the window and or position, but all I want to do is make the markers bigger.

I tried this but it doesn't like the markersize argument

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, markersize = 2)
for c, i, target_name, marker in zip("rgby", [0, 1, 2, 3], target_names,('*','x','1','d')):
    plt.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], c=c, label=target_name, marker=marker)
plt.legend()
plt.title(title)
plt.show
```

I know it must be super easy, but cant seem to find it, thanks!

Comment: You should check the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).  It sounds trite, but really you'll go far if you just check the documentation (in this case, the `s` parameter to scatter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `plt.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], c=c, label=target_name, marker=marker)` and `s = x` where x is the size you'd like eg.

`plt.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], s=40, c=c, label=target_name, marker=marker)`